# Tifinagh script in Latex

Tags: unicode, languages

How can use Tifinagh (Berber) in Latex. I tried the following code, but it does not work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,xunicode}
\newfontscript{Tifinagh}{Tamalout-Noufouss-UNICODE}
\begin{document}
\fontspec[Script=Tifinagh]{Code2D3C}
\end{document}
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You’ll have to supply some text between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` before the example can be tested. But try removing `xunicode`, `\newfontscript{Tifinagh}{Tamalout-Noufouss-UNICODE}`, and `\fontspec[Script=Tifinagh]{Code2D3C}`, and using instead `\setmainfont[Script=Tifinagh]{Tamalout-Noufouss-UNICODE}`. (Better yet, use Noto Sans Tifinagh, so that we can all try the example, because the web site for Tamalout Noufouss is gone.)

Comment: Text inside `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` can be anything. For example this: ⵏⴽⵉ ⴳⵉⵖ ⵙⵄⵉⴷ ⵎⵄⵏⴰⵏ (below `fontspec[Script=Tifinagh]{Code2D3C}`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking the table from wikipedia

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tifinagh_(Unicode_block)

[image]

I used lualatex, but xelatex should be good as well.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Ebrima}
%\setmainfont{Noto Sans Tifinagh}

\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{*{17}{c}}
&
0&
1&
2&
3&
4&
5&
6&
7&
8&
9&
A&
B&
C&
D&
E&
F
\\
U+2D3x&
ⴰ&
ⴱ&
ⴲ&
ⴳ&
ⴴ&
ⴵ&
ⴶ&
ⴷ&
ⴸ&
ⴹ&
ⴺ&
ⴻ&
ⴼ&
ⴽ&
ⴾ&
ⴿ
\\
U+2D4x&
ⵀ&
ⵁ&
ⵂ&
ⵃ&
ⵄ&
ⵅ&
ⵆ&
ⵇ&
ⵈ&
ⵉ&
ⵊ&
ⵋ&
ⵌ&
ⵍ&
ⵎ&
ⵏ
\\
U+2D5x&
ⵐ&
ⵑ&
ⵒ&
ⵓ&
ⵔ&
ⵕ&
ⵖ&
ⵗ&
ⵘ&
ⵙ&
ⵚ&
ⵛ&
ⵜ&
ⵝ&
ⵞ&
ⵟ
\\
U+2D6x&
ⵠ&
ⵡ&
ⵢ&
ⵣ&
ⵤ&
ⵥ&
ⵦ&
ⵧ&
&
&
&
&
&
&
&
ⵯ
\\
U+2D7x&
⵰&
&
&
&
&
&
&
&
&
&
&
&
&
&
&
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. When I use the code as is it does not give any result, but when I comment `\setmainfont{Ebrima}` and uncomment `\setmainfont{Noto Sans Tifinagh}`, it shows the letters in Tifinagh without Arabic numerals or Latin letters. I use either overleaf or sharelatex to generate results.

Comment: @Maanan Oh OK that means you don't have Ebrima (I just have it in windows, not sure where it came from, possibly part of office) but do have noto sans (which I didn't have) but the noto sams font must just have the Tifinagh  which is OK but means you need to switch families using fontspec (I just used the simplest \setmainfont version above which assumes the same font for the whole document. I'll update the answer later to use different fonts for latin