# How to insert the "yaz" symbol ⵣ in Latex equations

Tags: symbols, amsmath, unicode-math

I need to insert this [symbol ⵣ](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E2%B5%A3)  in Latex equations. However I couldn't find any font that gives a smooth symbol like in the image below:

[image]

How can I get a symbol that looks like the image above and be able to insert it in Latex equations.

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. community.

Comment: Did you search for "yaz utf" ? (https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2D63 https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2d63/index.htm)

Comment: @Sebastiano: it is [tifinagh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tifinagh)

Comment: @alberto: I could easily copy the symbol or insert it using its unicode. I would like to get variable edge thickness as shown in the image.

Comment: @Signiycello Excuse me ...after I have removed the last part of my comment.

Comment: This might help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/343762/82917

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a rotated Pisces symbol (♓︎) from Marvosym? It has variable edge thickness. You can make it a bit more narrow to resemble the Yaz character.

Or otherwise you can try to find a nice Tifinagh font and use that with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. I found a calligraphic font called [`caligraphie.ttf`](http://www.ircam.ma/?q=fr/node/26891) on http://www.ircam.ma (The Royal Moroccan Institute for Amazigh Culture).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\tifinagh}{caligraphie.ttf}
\begin{document}
% all engines
Marvosym \verb+\Pisces+ rotated: \rotatebox{90}{\Pisces}

Narrow version: \scalebox{0.7}[1]{\rotatebox{90}{\Pisces}}
% xelatex/lualatex only
Tifinagh font: {\scriptsize\tifinagh ⵣ}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Very interesting and truly a good solution.

Comment: This Tifinagh letter likely won't have math attributes, so it might need to be inserted with `\text`. If it's to be used frequently, better to create a macro to handle it properly.